# the link_to with confirm works only after reloading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
 **<%= link_to "Delete",(@article) ,method:"delete",data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete ?' } %>**
```

I have a rails app which lets the user create an account and posts delete and update add comments and get notifications using rails and Jquery

when I click the buttons which include confirm messages do not work until I refresh the page !!!why ?? what i should do ??

```
<%= link_to "Delete",(@article) ,method:"delete",data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete ?' } %>
```

Comment: Show us your application.js | Are you adding any content dynamically? | Are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: '//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.turbolinks
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#not-commented").mouseover(function () {
$(this).attr("src", "/assets/balloon2.svg");
})
$("#not-commented").mouseout(function () {
$(this).attr("src", "/assets/balloon.svg" );
});

$(".comments-count").click(function(){

  $(".view-comments").toggle();
});

});
$(".view-comments").hide();
})'

Comment: Please answer my other questions as well. You probably don't want to nest `$(document).ready` inside `$(document.on('page:change'`, but that shouldn't have an effect on link_to.

Comment: turbolinks :yes but no content added dynamically - without nesting the .ready inside .on('page:change') I get the same problem with {confirm} every time I have to refresh the page in order to interact with my toggle menu !!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your jquery is interfering with the link.  Make sure you do not have a "prevent_default" clause in your js file targeting that link or that would prevent the normal javascript from executing when the link is clicked.  Make sure your application.js file still has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Lastly, make sure in your layouts/application.html.erb file you still have:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Once that is done, reload the page and check your developer console to make sure that there is a data-confirm attribute in the link tag such as:

```
<a href="/articles/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete">
```

Comment: yes I have  //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs  in my aplication.js  and I have '<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>' in my layout application.html

Comment: Check to see if it works when you remove turbolinks from your app.  This is almost always the issue and keeps js code from executing because a new page isnt being loaded but only changed!

Comment: when I remove  '<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>' from the app there are no alerts appear and it saves the update directly!!

Comment: You need to keep the include application part and only remove the "data-turbolinks' part in that javascript_include_tag or else no js is run from your application.js file!  Try just removing the data-turbolinks' part and see if it works as expected.  If so, it's an issue with calling ready on your pages and being ignored by turbolinks